# Go Context: Store cancel() function returned by WithCancel(ctx)

Tags: go

I'm writing Go code that needs to create and cancel Go routines based on state updates that are received over a channel. The created Go routines will go onto create additional Go Routines.

There are several ways to do this including manually creating Done channels, the [tomb](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/tomb.v2) package, and the context package.

One issue with using the context package is that the code creating the Go routines returns preventing access to the cancel() function returned by WithCancel(ctx). Is it safe to store the cancel() function in a map to be called later? Even If this is safe, is it idiomatic?

```golang
func (c *Controller) addCluster(ctx context.Context, clusterId string){
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    c.clusterCancel[clusterId] = cancel
    
    clusterStateCh := make(chan cluster.State)
    newCluster := cluster.NewCluster(clusterId, clusterStateCh)
    c.protected.clusters[clusterId] = newCluster
    go newCluster.Run(ctx)
}
```

Comment: If you really need multiple contexts and multiple cancel functions, you can do this. That said, dealing with multiple contexts from acentral function means maybe you should create separate goroutines and create the contexts in them. Hard to say without knowing the exact problem though.

Comment: The cancel funcs are not going to blow up later if that's what you mean, it's up to you whether this pattern is a good idea or not.